# Как запускать приложения в Kivy Launcher, если приложение использует дополнительные модули?

Tags: python, kivy

Создал приложение в Kivy.
Оно использует модуль *geocoder*.
Как я могу запустить это приложение через Kivy Launcher?

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос запуском приложения из PyDroid3 под Android.
В PyDroid3 Kivy уже установлен.
Также есть терминал. Установил нужные модули через pip.